# Contribution pages don't work

Tags: wordpress, contribution-page

My contribution pages (that I use to collect new members on a website) are completely crazy, just showing the page title repeatedly some 10 or more times.

[image]

But when I try to do a test-drive everything looks fine.

[image]

Based on a similar question here, I tried to create a new page from scratch, but the problem persists.
No idea where to start digging :/

Comment: This may be CMS specific so perhaps you can explain eg is this WordPress and are you using shortcodes, or is this drupal - perhaps pasting the path to the page you are seeing this on - with the domain removed if you want to keep private

Comment: @petednz-fuzion yes its wordpress. I'm not using any shortcodes, actually I'm just clicking on the "Live Page" link from the contribution pages list. The path looks like "?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1"

Comment: added WP as a tag as I suspect it is a WP issue that I won't be able to guess at

Comment: This is the wp demo site by contrast - http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

Comment: and this is the preview page url for comparison http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&reset=1&id=1

Comment: can you disable any WP plugins or themes - eg whatever is giving you the background image

Comment: @petednz-fuzion tried a simple theme: problem persists. disabled all plugins except civicrm: problem persists. Why do you think this is a wp issue?

Comment: Fair question. I have no idea. I have worked on hundreds of sites and never seen this type of problem. Most of our work is Drupal. As I read most tickets on SE I feel I see more unusual outcomes with WP users, perhaps because of theme and plugin conflicts

Comment: What is your basepage set to in `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1`?

Comment: @ChristianWach it's blank. just the site root

Comment: That's the problem then - your homepage template probably shows a list of posts, which is why it's trying to render multiple instances. Furthermore, if it's only showing excerpts then it won't render the CiviCRM content. You need a base page set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a WordPress base page. Create an empty page (e.g. titled "CiviCRM" with the slug "civicrm") and enter the page slug in the basepage field in `wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fuf&reset=1`. Your form(s) should then render properly.

Comment: Glad you could explain that for Nuno.

Comment: ah yes, that solved it! thank you so much :)